# Typescript linting errors on VSCode with Yarn v3.2.3

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, yarnpkg, yarn-v3

Whenever I intend to create `react` or the `next app` with the new `yarn v3.2.3`, my VS Code throws linting errors explaining in the picture below.
Mainly, the linter throws `ts(2307)` aka `Cannot find module 'next' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)` error.

[image: Linting error on VSCode]

Comment: I have the same issue with vite and react-ts. Have you managed to solve this?

Comment: @MichaelParkadze Unfortunately, I couldn't find any solutions. I think the errors come from node_modules, as `yarn` simply keeps all the modules inside `.yarn` directory and the VScode linter can't find the moduels because it is trying to search inside the `node_modules` directory. It could be errors from `yarn v3+`. Well, using `yarn version 1.x.x` works fine. But for the permanent solution, I am using the default `npm` as it has been improved significantly.

Comment: I think I found a solution, posted it below. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I found that having .vscode folder with a file called settings.json as the following helped with this issue. I get a prompt form vscode that asks if I wish it to use the workspace typescript and once I select yes, all the linting red errors are gone and I can work.

I think this is something regarding yarn workspaces. Hope this helps :)

```
{
  "typescript.tsdk": ".yarn/sdks/typescript/lib",
  "search.exclude": {
    "**/.yarn": true,
    "**/.pnp.*": true
  },
  "prettier.prettierPath": ".yarn/sdks/prettier/index.js",
  "typescript.enablePromptUseWorkspaceTsdk": true
}
```

Comment: No changes 
Still facing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if you are still interested in using Yarn 3+ in your current or future projects, please follow the following steps to set up Yarn 3+ properly in VS Code.

1. Open your Next.js project using VSCode
2. Install [ZipFS](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=arcanis.vscode-zipfs) extension
3. Run the following command

   ```
   yarn dlx @yarnpkg/sdks vscode
   ```

   which will create a `settings.json` inside `.vscode` folder of your workspace.
4. Next, open any `.ts` or `.tsx` file in your workspace, and press `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `P`
5. Type `typescipt` until you see some options related to TypeScript. Choose `TypeScript: Select TypeScript Version...`
6. Finally, choose `Use Workspace Version`

If the setup is done properly, you will see `settings.json` in `.vscode`, which contains configuration the same or similar to one answered by Michael earlier. The second thing that you will notice is the `sdks` directory in your `.yarn` directory, which contains TypeScript server configuration relative to your workspace.

For further reading, please go to [Yarn Editor SDKs](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/editor-sdks)